# Conexion a SQL-Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Soy nuevo en esto de la conexión de PHP con SQL-server y me ha dado un poco duro, pues no logro realizar la conexión, al instalar los drivers y componentes necesarios. Al momento de compilar mi código donde estoy haciendo la conexión el sublime text, me envía el siguiente error:

`php startup unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll'`

Comment: Hola, verificaste si tienes ese driver instalado? te aseguraste que php7 soporta el driver sqlsrv?

Comment: Lo vas a hostear en un Windows Server con IIS y qué versión?

Comment: Edgar hice la instalación y la ejecución de los pasos como aparece en la documentación, de muchas formas, copié los dll directamente a la carpeta de extensiónes de PHP, los instale con el asistente en la página de Microsoft, revise que estuvieran en la carpeta, pero ninguna de estas formas ha podido ser efectiva, pues cada que ejecutó un script PHP me dice manda el mismo error... Cómo puedo asegurarme si PHP 7 soporta el Drive?

Comment: Alejandro, No entendí tu pregunta 

Comment: Verifica que los .dll sean compatibles con la arquitectura de tu computadora y que esten habilitados en tu php.ini

Comment: El estar habilitado significa que no estén con los ";" al inicio... En ese caso, si están habilitados.. y cómo puedo verificar que los .dll sean compatibles?